# Aerospike Key-value Store using Go-client

Tags: go, key-value-store, aerospike

What is the data model to store millions of record efficiently in the aerospike database?

Use case : storing millions of bid(value) for a particular id(key) and 
also need to iterate over the values and operate on them as fast as possible and store them separately.

Currently :using **set** as the key and **bin** as the value.

Comment: "ASAP" isn't a thing on Stack Overflow. It's your own problem.

Comment: Feel free to open a discussion on [Aerospike's user forum](https://discuss.aerospike.com/c/client-libraries/go-client).